# No route matches using rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have the following routes:

**config/routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The controller specs are under the folder `spec/controllers/api/v1/`.

**spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:**

```
module Api
  module V1
    RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
      let!(:users) { create_list(:user, 10) }

      describe 'GET /v1/users' do
        before { get :index }
        # Already tried `get '/v1/users'`, got the same error

        it 'should return 10 users' do
          expect(JSON.parse(response).size).to eq(10)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Once I run the tests I receive the following error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"api/v1/users"}

Note that it "infers" the `api` *part* from somewhere, but my routes are like these:

```
v1/users
v1/users/:id
...
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Side note: it's probably better to do `RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController` instead of putting it inside `Api::V1` module.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because you are namespacing your test with `Api::V1::UsersController`, but your route is defined within the *scope* of Api.  That's why your routes are not under `/api`

Try removing the Api module from the controller and test or changing `scope module: :api` to `namespace :api`

Alternatively, you could keep it all as-is and make the `get` request to your `v1_users_path` or whatever the corresponding path is when you run `rails routes` (instead of `:index`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It's strange because if I simply go in browser and hit `http://localhost:3000/v1/users` it works really fine. I can't see any problem in the actual routes configuration. Also I'm dealing with API, so I'm not sure I have any access like this helpers `v1_users_path`.

Comment: What does `rails routes` output for you?

Comment: Outputs this: `GET    /v1/users(.:format)       api/v1/users#index`

Comment: Hmm, I just set up a test project with the same routes and controller as you and the test passed.  Are you requiring `rails_helper` in your test?

Comment: Oh thanks for helping me out. Yes, I'm requiring that `rails_helper`. Can you put it in a simple repo (on github?), so I can take a look what I'm missing?

Comment: I just made a new rails project, added rspec and changed the files in the gist below

https://gist.github.com/SMaxOwok/cdee164d883e0828ae4932228bfd5b34

Comment: Thanks for the gist. Well, I couldn't find where I did the mistake, so I created a fresh new project and setup everything again and now it's working. I guess it was a problem somewhere.